# enable debugf in SystemC

Tags: c++, systemc

I was looking at the source of SystemC and saw that there are things like:

```
#define DEBUGF \
    if (0) std::cout << "sc_cor_pthread.cpp(" << __LINE__ << ") "
```

and later on there are lines such as:

```
    DEBUGF << this << ": sc_cor_pthread::sc_cor_pthread()" << std::endl;
```

(these are from `sc_cor_pthread.cpp`)

I have already enabled debug option when configuring using `../configure --enable-debug` but it doesn't seem to activate these kinds of stuff. How am I supposed to turn these on instead of manually modifying source?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your compile line:

```
-DDEBUGF
```

Comment: I think that is supposed to work for `#ifdef` not `#define`. anyway my question was more about enabling this in configuration rather than modifying the source or the generated makefile. I did end up changing `if (0)` to `if (1)` in the source but the question remains..

Comment: Oh, right you are. Should have looked a little closer. Seems like someone just wanted to quickly remove the print statements as in some versions the if (0) is not there (line 66): http://code.google.com/p/syscpar/source/browse/trunk/code/current/systemc-2.2.0/src/sysc/kernel/sc_cor_pthread.cpp?spec=svn21&r=21 So it  looks like it was not implemented in a way to change this easily.